# How to name an ArrayList after a String parameter

Tags: java, string, arraylist, parameters

How can I send a string to a method that receives a string as a parameter, and use that parameter being received to name a new ArrayList?

example:

```
public void new(String name){


        ArrayList name = new ArrayList();

}
```

Why doesnt it works, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You want to name an `ArrayList` after a variable? I think I would rather create a `HashMap`, and map the variable to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: It doesn't work because variable names are assigned at compile time, not runtime. As @Saviour suggests, a common alternative is having a `HashMap` key-value pair like so: `{nameStr, nameArrayListObj}`

Comment: For what purpose? You won't have any advantage from this, accept you're trying something dirty with reflection.

Comment: What did you mean by "to name a new ArrayList" ? Why you are declaring `name` again while you already passed it ?

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem, read about [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) and then ask about the thing that you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. 
Local variable names is just for you, choose what you want.

But if you need a different ArrayList from a parameter, you should use an `Map<String,ArrayList>`. By doing that, you can put into the map an arraylist as value and use the name as the key for this value.